# UWP Unpairing with device Failed

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, enumeration

I'm currently developing a functionality to existing UWP app to test device's bluetooth device's capability. With that I'm currently facing 2 problems 1 one them is main one:
I'm building bluetooth capability based on Device Enumeration and pairing Sample from Windows Universal samples. [Link here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs) . I can successfully find and enumerate BT devices and even pair with them, but in a Weird Way I'm unable to Unpair with device.
Code I've made is found here, I added whole class for you to be able to test is fully if needed:

```
class UWP_Bluetooth
{
    DeviceWatcher deviceWatcher;
    public StringBuilder btNetworkInfo = new StringBuilder();
    //EventHandler<BluetoothWin32AuthenticationEventArgs> authHandler = new EventHandler<BluetoothWin32AuthenticationEventArgs>(handleAuthRequests);
    //BluetoothWin32Authentication authenticator = new BluetoothWin32Authentication(authHandler);

    public ObservableCollection<RfcommChatDeviceDisplay> ResultCollection
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void SearchForBTNetworks()
    {
        ResultCollection = new ObservableCollection<RfcommChatDeviceDisplay>();

        string[] requestedProperties = new string[] { "System.Devices.Aep.DeviceAddress", "System.Devices.Aep.IsConnected" };

        deviceWatcher = DeviceInformation.CreateWatcher("(System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}\")",
                                                        requestedProperties,
                                                        DeviceInformationKind.AssociationEndpoint);
        //deviceWatcher.Added += DeviceWatcher_Added;
        deviceWatcher.Added += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformation>((watcher, deviceInfo) =>
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Something added");

            // Since we have the collection databound to a UI element, we need to update the collection on the UI thread.
            // Make sure device name isn't blank
            if (deviceInfo.Name != "")
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(deviceInfo.Name);
                //Debug.WriteLine(deviceInfo.Id);
                ResultCollection.Add(new RfcommChatDeviceDisplay(deviceInfo));
                //rootPage.NotifyUser(
                //String.Format("{0} devices found.", ResultCollection.Count),
                //NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }

        });
        deviceWatcher.Updated += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>((watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Something updated");
            foreach (RfcommChatDeviceDisplay rfcommInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
            {
                if (rfcommInfoDisp.Id == deviceInfoUpdate.Id)
                {
                    rfcommInfoDisp.Update(deviceInfoUpdate);
                    break;
                }
            }

        });
        deviceWatcher.Removed += new TypedEventHandler<DeviceWatcher, DeviceInformationUpdate>((watcher, deviceInfoUpdate) =>

        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Something removed");
            // Find the corresponding DeviceInformation in the collection and remove it
            foreach (RfcommChatDeviceDisplay rfcommInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
            {
                if (rfcommInfoDisp.Id == deviceInfoUpdate.Id)
                {
                    //Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Name + " Removed");
                    ResultCollection.Remove(rfcommInfoDisp);
                    break;
                }
            }

        });

        deviceWatcher.Start();
        Debug.WriteLine("Started searching BT devices");
        //base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    public void StopSearchingBTNetworks()
    {
        if (deviceWatcher.Status == DeviceWatcherStatus.Started)
        {
            deviceWatcher.Stop();
            Debug.WriteLine("Stopped searching BT devices");
        }
    }

    public string DisplayBTDevices()
    {

        btNetworkInfo.AppendLine("ID,Name,Type,Pairing");
        foreach (RfcommChatDeviceDisplay rfcommInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
        {
            btNetworkInfo.Append($"{rfcommInfoDisp.Id}\t");
            btNetworkInfo.Append($"{rfcommInfoDisp.Name}\t");
            btNetworkInfo.Append($"{rfcommInfoDisp.GetType()}\t");
            btNetworkInfo.Append($"{rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.IsPaired}\t");
            Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Id);
            btNetworkInfo.AppendLine();
            //Debug.WriteLine("\n"); 
        }
        return btNetworkInfo.ToString();
    }

    public async Task<int> PairWithSelectedAsync(string SSIDToPairWith)
    {
        int returnvalue = 5;
        foreach (RfcommChatDeviceDisplay rfcommInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
        {
            if (rfcommInfoDisp.Name == SSIDToPairWith)
            {
                returnvalue = 3;
                Debug.WriteLine("Found device to connect to");
                Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Name);
                Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Id);
                if (rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.CanPair == true)
                {
                    //rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Properties.

                    DevicePairingResult pairingResult = await rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.PairAsync();
                    if (pairingResult.Status == 0)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Connected with bluetooth device");
                        returnvalue = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnvalue = (int)pairingResult.Status;

                    }
                }

            }
        }
        if (returnvalue == 5)
            Debug.WriteLine("Didn't find device");

        return returnvalue;
    }

    public async Task<int> UnpairWithSelectedAsync(string SSIDToUnpairWith)
    {
        int returnvalue = 0;
        foreach (RfcommChatDeviceDisplay rfcommInfoDisp in ResultCollection)
        {
            if (rfcommInfoDisp.Name == SSIDToUnpairWith)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Found device to unconnect from");
                //Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Name);
                //Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.Id);
                Debug.WriteLine(rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.IsPaired);
                //rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Properties.
                DeviceUnpairingResult pairingResult = await rfcommInfoDisp.DeviceInformation.Pairing.UnpairAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine("Unpairing result: " +pairingResult.Status);
                if (pairingResult.Status == 0 )
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Successfully unpaired with bluetooth device");
                    returnvalue = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    returnvalue = (int)pairingResult.Status;
                }
                //Debug.WriteLine("\n");
            }
        }
        return returnvalue;
    }
}

public class RfcommChatDeviceDisplay : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DeviceInformation deviceInfo;

    public RfcommChatDeviceDisplay(DeviceInformation deviceInfoIn)
    {
        deviceInfo = deviceInfoIn;
        //UpdateGlyphBitmapImage();
    }

    public DeviceInformation DeviceInformation
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceInfo;
        }

        private set
        {
            deviceInfo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceInfo.Id;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceInfo.Name;
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage GlyphBitmapImage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Update(DeviceInformationUpdate deviceInfoUpdate)
    {
        deviceInfo.Update(deviceInfoUpdate);
        //UpdateGlyphBitmapImage();
    }
    /*
    private async void UpdateGlyphBitmapImage()
    {
        DeviceThumbnail deviceThumbnail = await deviceInfo.GetGlyphThumbnailAsync();
        BitmapImage glyphBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        await glyphBitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(deviceThumbnail);
        GlyphBitmapImage = glyphBitmapImage;
        OnPropertyChanged("GlyphBitmapImage");
    }
    */

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Currently main problem is lack of ability to unpair with device already paired with. 
Bonus: If any of you know how to remove prompt or popup that appears if I attempt to pair with Bluetooth device (the device itself has 0 security which mans no asking for any PIN or prompt) that would also help a lot.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Have you tried to test 'unpairring' in UWP official code 
[BluetoothRfcommChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothRfcommChat/cs) sample to see if it works on your side?